even after downloading python 3 extensions... it shows no such file or directory
it shows this when i try to access colcon-argcomplete file
cd: /usr/share/colcon_argcomplete/hook/: No such file or directory

What happens when you run sudo apt install python3-pip && pip3 install colcon-argcomplete ? What are the results of lsb_release -a ?

To verify the exact installation directory for Python packages installed by pip3 without root privileges in your environment, you can use the command: python3 -m site Use sudo python3 -m site for system-provided Python packages.

Why are you trying to go to that specific directory? What made you think this is where the files you are looking for would be?
